# Google Sheets Formula for Grouping Data and then finding the Median Value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Example data:**

| Category | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Blue | 200 |
| Blue | 200 |
| Red | 360 |
| Green | 300 |
| Red | 400 |
| Green | 300 |
| Yellow | 0 |
| Red | 0 |
| Pink | 800 |
| Silver | 900 |
| ---- | ---- |
| MEDIAN | 330 |
| MEDIAN OF CATEGORIES | ??? |

The formula being used to calculate the median of all values (above 0) is

```
=MEDIAN(FILTER(B2:B11,B2:B11>0))
```

What formula would I need to use to Sum the Values of each category, then find the Median of the categories?

At this time I can only do this with a pivot table and the result is 760.

In its actual use case, the unique colours will change regularly and I could end up with several hundred.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this

`=MEDIAN(FILTER(SUMIF(A2:A, UNIQUE(A2:A), B2:B), SUMIF(A2:A, UNIQUE(A2:A), B2:B)>0))`

This works for me:
[image]